# Android SDK beginner question

Tags: android

I'm a n00b developer at my second attempt to use the Android SDK. I'm
developing on the Mac platform and I've noticed that the latest
version of the SDK doesn't include anything except the tools (so I
have no plugins, no targets to choose from inside the package I
downloaded).

So I tried to use the Android SDK and AVD Manager to download and
install some, however, I got this error:
Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/

I went to the settings and checked the box to force fetching via HTTP,
but no result. I was suggested to look for a configuration file, but
couldn't find any.

Any suggestions? I'm dying to get my hands dirty with the SDK.

Comment: That URL is missing "repository.xml" from the end of it. Also, if you use an HTTP proxy, you need to enter the settings in the SDK manager.

Comment: Might want to move this to an answer Christopher so it can be marked as such.

It's definitely the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I've seen that error, I've just retried the download several times and eventually it went through.  I've only run into it when I was behind a proxy, but that might not be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a Android tutorial, step by step.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html

Answer (score 0):

Its means that you are behind a proxy.Go tools->options in your android SDK manager and enter your http Proxy server and port and it'll work.